# Attaching Changed Event to Dynamically Created Radiobuttons

Tags: asp.net, events, radio-button

I'm dynamically creating a load of radiobuttons in code behind (vb.net on load) and am wondering how I should create the events on them. I have a gridview with two columns and each row has a radiobutton in both columns that are in a group together (fyi group means check one, the other is unchecked). I want to change the background colour to yellow on whichever one is checked. How best would I do this? Javascript (catch all radio button change events), JQuery (catch all radio button change events) or Vb.net (attach method on creation)? Here is how I'm creating them;

```
Dim r As RadioButton
    Dim l As Label
    Dim radioBtnNumber As Integer = 0
    For row As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If GridView1.Rows(row).RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim x As Integer = 0
            For Each tc As TableCell In GridView1.Rows(row).Cells
                l = New Label()
                l.Text = tc.Text
                If (x = 1) Or (x = 2) Then
                    r = New RadioButton()
                    r.GroupName = String.Format("RdBtnGroup{0}", row)
                    r.ID = radioBtnNumber.ToString
                    //Could add in event here. Tried this but didn't work
                    //r.Attributes.Add("OnCheckedChanged", "radiobuttonChecked()")
                    tc.Controls.Add(r)
                    radioBtnNumber = radioBtnNumber + 1
                End If
                tc.Controls.Add(l)
                x = x + 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

That code is actually more confusing that it should be because the gridview is actually flipped (veritical as opposed horizontal). So I have radiobuttons named 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc with 0 and 1 in a group, 2 and 3 in a group etc and I just want to catch which one has been changed. Bear in mind though that I need the name of the RB or it's position in my gridView as I'll have to change the background colour of the RB it's paired with also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add line (code is C#, translate to VB):

```
r.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radiobuttonChecked);
```

when you create the `RadioButton`. `radiobuttonChecked` should be method of your webpage:

```
protected void radiobuttonChecked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...
}
```

where you will be able to cast sender to `RadioButton` and analyze its properties. This will cause a postback to the server, where you can modify the radio buttons.

If you want to do it on the client, then you can first assign CssClass (e.g. "rbClass") to the same string for all of them and also use

```
r.Attributes.Add("pairName", "<name for the pair of radiobuttons>")
```

Then add javascript to your page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".rbClass").change(function(){
    // here you look at $(this).attr and 
    // adjust its and its pair's css accordingly
  })
});
```

Comment: Converting your C# gave me r.CheckedChanged += New System.EventHandler(Me.radiobuttonChecked) which isn't valid. Trying javascript now.

Comment: @killianmcc - I do not know VB.NET syntax to add an event delegate, but Google search on "VB.NET syntax to add CheckedChanged event" produced http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/05/dynamic-checkbox-checkedchanged-event.html which has a VB.NET example.